# space check on unix machines

Tags: shell, disk-usage

I am having space issues on 1 of the UNIX servers. I am executing the below command to check the space utilization. But this command is very slow and takes hours of time to give the result.

```
du -sg * | sort -nr >> /my/home/dir/space_20150303
```

Is there any better way to check the space utilization?

Comment: You can use `df` to get the current available disk space quickly, though it won't give you a breakdown. You can also use `ncdu`; after the first run, if you press R, it refreshes quite quickly.

Comment: what `-g` option means? There is no `-g` in `GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb                                            `

Comment: Are you sure it's _Linux_? `-g` (for GiB) is present on some BSDs, but not in `du` implementations commonly found on Linux (GNU, busybox)

Comment: If the filesystem is being accessed over the network (NFS or CIFS), you can speed up the disk usage check by logging into the server and running du there.

Answer (score 1):

There's no miracle: unless the system is already tracking that for you, the disk usage command has to traverse all the directory entries, read their size and compute the sum.

If the filesystem is mounted remotely (NFS, Samba, …), run `du` on the server if possible, it'll be a lot faster than running it on a remote client.

Since you want to know about all your files, there's a way to track your disk usage and get instant feedback. However this needs to be enabled by the system administrator. This way is [quotas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota). It's possible to activate quotas without setting a limit; that way you still get the tracking of space used by each user.

Answer (score 0):

```
df
```

to check File System Disk Space Usage

```
df -a
```

to display Information of all File System Disk Space Usage

```
df -h
```

to show Disk Space Usage in Human Readable Format and Information of File System in GB

```
df -hT /home
```

to display Information of `/home` File System

Answer (score 0):

Often it could be just a few huge files that are using up unexpected space. Finding these can be quick, not usually more than a minute or 2.

Look for these with

```
cd (mount point)
find . -xdev -size +20000 -ls > /tmp/bigfiles
```

The mount point could be say / for root file system or /home which ever you are interested in. eg cd /home

The -xdev means do not cross mount points into another file system, as you are only interested in the file system that is full.

The +20000 means only look for files or directories bigger than 20000 x 512 byte blocks. Eg 20000 is approx 10 mb.

The -ls says to list the file or directory info similarly to ls -ld.

I usually send the output to /tmp/bigfiles so I can fix each problem then look at the next problem without having to redo the find cmd.

Use
    less /tmp/bigfiles to view the output of the find cmd.